# How do I format custom crontabs in /etc/cron.d/?

Tags: cron, supervisor

My understanding is that I can add system jobs with simple schedules to `/etc/cron.hourly/`, `/etc/cron.daily/` and so on, and system jobs with custom schedules to `/etc/cron.d/`.

> But in a large IT department, where several people might look after a server, then the directory /etc/cron.d is probably the best place to install crontabs - it's a central point and saves searching for them! [(CronHowTo)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

I have created `/etc/cron.d/testing` with the following contents:

```
# /etc/cron.d/testing: crontab entries for report generation

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

15 13    * * 3   root   /usr/bin/supervisorctl start reports
00 16    * * 4   root   /usr/bin/supervisorctl start reports
```

The file has the following properties:

```
user@server:/etc/cron.d$ ls -la
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 14 12:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 146 root root 12288 Jul 14 13:48 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   188 Feb 20  2014 anacron
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   102 Feb  9  2013 .placeholder
-rwxr--r--   1 root root   286 Jul 14 13:43 testing
```

I rebooted the machine at 1pm on Thursday, expecting it to fire off a report at 13:15. (The plan was to test this invocation, but also schedule it for 4pm every Friday.)

But nothing happened. There is no error (or any event) in `/var/log/syslog`, or the Supervisor logs. I use the same command in `/etc/cron.daily/testing` and it works:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/supervisorctl start reports
```

...and I can invoke the Supervisor job independently. So I don't think the problem is in the Supervisor job, or in my invocation.

What am I doing wrong? (And where is the problem being logged?)

Comment: You run yr jobs as `root` so it cannot be a `cron.allow` / `cron.deny` issue. Did you check that your `cron` log level ? Look up the last line of `/etc/init/cron.conf`. I set it normally to `cron -L 7` sometimes to 15 when I need to run a lot of jobs over a short period of time for audits ...

Comment: Is `supervisorctl` interactive in any way ?

Comment: @Cbhihe thanks for the questions, turned out it was a text formatting error on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format used for the crontab file `/etc/cron.d/testing` is correct. (It should be, it was copied from `/etc/cron.d/anacron`)

The problem was that I modified it from Windows and probably messed up the line endings. I re-cloned `anacron`, edited it on Ubuntu, and everything worked.

(I still don't know where the error message, if any, was logged.)